# Exception handling classes in C++

Tags: c++, exception, namespaces

I have an assignment for my OOP class to create a rudimentary calculator. The goal of the assignment is to practice namespaces and exception handling.

I will paste the text of the problem for clarity:

You have to implement the class Kalkulator which solves rudimentary mathematical expressions and returns the result as an integer.

The class Kalkulator should be put in a namespace called Matematika. The whole class needs to be implemented in the header file without a .cpp file.

You have to define two exceptions and throw them in the correct situation(they are caught in the main function)

- IncorrectDataExc put the class into the namespace Matematika->Exceptions
- InvalidOperationExc put the class into the namespace Matematika->Exceptions

and they also gave me the main function:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
#include "Kalkulator.h" 
#include "IncorrectDataExc.h" 
#include "InvalidOperationExc.h" 

using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
    string s; 
    getline(cin, s); 

    try 
    {
        Matematika::Kalkulator kalkulator;
        cout << kalkulator.izracunaj(s) << endl;
    } 
    catch(Matematika::Exceptions::IncorrectDataExc) 
    { 
        cout << "Exception IncorrectData" << endl;
    } 
    catch(Matematika::Exceptions::InvalidOperationExc) 
    { 
        cout << "Exception InvalidOperation" << endl;
    } 

    return 0; 
}
```

The problem I'm having is that i don't know what to throw when i get an exception and i don't know how the InvalidOperationExc  and IncorrectDataExc classes should look like because i don't know what the catch functions are actually catching(an object?)

I have to create 3 header files:

```
IncorrectDataExc.h
InvalidOperationExc.h 
Kalkulator.h
```

This is what i have so far

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <sstream>


using namespace std;

namespace Matematika{

class Kalkulator{
private:


public:
    int izracunaj(string mojString)
    {
        int prviBroj = 0;
        int drugiBroj = 0;
        char operacija = ' ';
        stringstream ss(mojString);
        ss >> prviBroj >> operacija >> drugiBroj;
        if(operacija != '*' && operacija != '+' && operacija != '/' && operacija != '-')
        {
            Matematika::Exceptions::InvalidOperationExc greska1;
            throw greska1;
        }
        if(prviBroj % drugiBroj != 0)
        {
            Matematika::Exceptions::IncorrectDataExc greska2;
            throw greska2;
        }
    }
};
}
```

and I'm getting some errors:

```
'Exceptions': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type
'InvalidOperationExc' : is not a member of 'Matematika'
'InvalidOperationExc' : undeclared identifier
 missing ';' before identifier 'greska1'
'greska1' : undeclared identifier
'greska1' : undeclared identifier
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. The part that is confusing me the most is this

```
    catch(Matematika::Exceptions::IncorrectDataExc)
```

what is the catch function receiving?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty self explanatory errors:

> 'InvalidOperationExc' : is not a member of 'Matematika'

In other words, it doesn't exist. This

```
 Matematika::Exceptions::InvalidOperationExc greska1;
```

resulted in the error. You should either change the `InvalidOperationExc` to something else or create it in `Matematika`.

Comment: I created a header file called InvalidOperationExc.h
and inside it i wrote

    namespace Matematika{

 namespace Exceptions{

  class InvalidOperationExc{};
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

`int izrakunaj()` doesn't need `Matematika::...` to access members of namespace Matematika because it is also a member.

```
namespace ns
{
    int integer; //ns::integer
    void set0(){integer=0;} //modifies the variable above
    void set1(){ns::integer=1;} //modifies the variable below

    namespace ns
    {
        int integer; //ns::ns::integer
    }

}
```

Comment: I fixed that in the code but I still get the same errors.

Comment: @nixpix The file with izrakunaj() doesn't `#include` the headers that contain the exceptions, so they don't exist for that file.